# Video defects when playing games or watching fullscreen videos

Tags: graphics-card

I have the following blue defect in video (only in fullscreen) and games.

I have tried:

- Reinstalling the driver
- Taking the GFX card physically out and back in
- Changing resolutions

The video card is a Radeon 9600 so its nearly 10 years old.

Apart from in games and full screen video the card works fine.

Ill also note that it doesn't matter which encoding the video is in, there is a problem for all formats.

Any other ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I would update the drivers and check refresh rates, however, if this used to work and it doesn't all of a sudden, I think the most likely cause is simply that it is failing - 10 years for electronics is an awful long time.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like the video card is physically failing.  Considering the age of the video card, you should consider replacing the video card.

While AGP video cards are becoming harder to find, there are still good options such as the [VisionTek ATI Radeon HD 3650 1 GB DDR2 AGP Graphics Card](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003A4H696).  Replacing the video card will also enable significantly faster performance as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to test your card with [Video Memory Stress Test](http://majorgeeks.com/Video_Memory_Stress_Test__d5896.html) before replacing, but I tend to agree with others - it's time to change.